# Timestamp arithmetic in bash

Tags: bash, date, awk, unix-timestamp, iso8601

Say I have two log files (`input.log` and `output.log`) with the following format:

```
2012-01-16T12:00:00 12345678
```

The first field is the processing timestamp and the second is a unique ID. I'm trying to find:

1. The records from `input.log` which don't have a corresponding record for that ID in `output.log`
2. The records from `input.log` which have a record for that ID, *but* the difference in the timestamps exceeds 5 seconds

I have a [workaround solution with MySQL](https://gist.github.com/1623177), but I'd ideally like to remove the database component and handle it with a shell script.

I have the following, which returns the lines of `input.log` with an added column if `output.log` contains the ID:

```
join -a1 -j2 -o 0 1.1 2.1 <(sort -k2,2 input.log) <(sort -k2,2 output.log)
```

Example output:

```
10111 2012-01-16T10:00:00 2012-01-16T10:00:04
11562 2012-01-16T11:00:00 2012-01-16T11:00:10
97554 2012-01-16T09:00:00
```

**Main question**:

Now that I have this information, how can I go about computing the differences between the 2 timestamps and discarding those over 5 seconds apart? I hit some problems processing the ISO 8601 timestamp with `date` (specifically the `T`) and assumed there must be a better way.

<sub>*Edit: GNU coreutils supports ISO 8601 since late 2011, not long after this question was asked. This is likely no longer an issue for anyone. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107773/8742)*</sub>

**Secondary question**:

Is there perhaps a way to rework the entire approach, for instance into a single `awk` script? My knowledge of processing multiple files and setting up the correct inequalities for the output conditions was the limiting factor here, hence the approach above.

Comment: back when I had to do awk computing of time differences, that rolled over day, month, year boundaries, I would have killed to have a freebie database to do the calcs for me ;-). It's definitely possible to calc time diffs with awk. Search some of my early posts here for some ideas. ALSO don't feel bad about your current approach. Unix toolkit pipeline philosophy is all about breaking your problem down into solvable parts. You have solved a big chunk and your just one more awk filter away from having it done. On to the next problem! (in awk `sub("T", " ", $2) & $3` to elim T in time. Good luck.

Comment: If you have GNU date, you can use it to convert to UNIX time, perform math and then convert it back.

Comment: I have made an attempt to solve your question in an awk one-liner (big one-liner). Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `GNU awk`, then you can try something like this -

```
gawk '
NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} 
!($2 in a) {print $2,$1; next} 
($2 in a) {
  "date +%s -d " $1 | getline var1;
  "date +%s -d " a[$2] | getline var2;
  var3 = var2 - var1;
  if (var3 > 4) print $2, $1, a[$2]
}' output.log input.log
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat input.log 
2012-01-16T09:00:00 9
2012-01-16T10:00:00 10
2012-01-16T11:00:00 11

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat output.log 
2012-01-16T10:00:04 10
2012-01-16T11:00:10 11
2012-01-16T12:00:00 12

[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk '
NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} 
!($2 in a) {print $2,$1; next} 
($2 in a) {"date +%s -d " $1 | getline var1; "date +%s -d " a[$2] | getline var2;var3=var2-var1;if (var3>4) print $2,$1,a[$2] }' output.log input.log
9 2012-01-16T09:00:00
11 2012-01-16T11:00:00 2012-01-16T11:00:10
```

#### Explanation:

- `NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}`

We start of by storing the first field in your output.log file in an array indexed on second field. We use `next` to prevent the other `pattern{action}` statements from running. Using `NR==FNR` allows us to slurp the output.log file completely.

- `!($2 in a) {print $2,$1; next}`

Once the output.log file is completed. We start with the input.log file. We check if any second field present in input.log file is not present in our array (i.e output.log file). If found we print it. We continue this action until we have printed out all of those fields.

- `($2 in a) {"date +%s -d " $1 | getline var1; "date +%s -d " a[$2] | getline var2; var3=var2-var1; if (var3 > 4) print $2,$1,a[$2] }`

In this we look for fields that **are** present in both files. When we find those fields, we need to put in our logic to calculate the difference. We use the system command to find the date. Now system command by default prints to STDOUT and we have no control over them. So we pipe the output and capture the output using `awk` `getline` function and store it in a variable (var1 and var2). Once both dates are stored in a variable we do the difference and store in var3, if var3 is found to be > 4, we print it in the format you desire.

Comment: I really like this. I had `getline` working but couldn't figure out the correct use of `next` for my purposes.

Comment: One comment to add: It has the same issue as user unknown's solution, namely that the ISO 8601 date string is parsed incorrectly due to it misinterpreting the `T` as a time zone designator. For my use case it doesn't present a problem, since the errors cancel out, but it's worth mentioning here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @cbuckley. Honestly I am not too good with the `date` function in `bash` at all. But, I will try to remember that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I went with:

```
cat input.log
2012-01-16T09:00:00 9
2012-01-16T10:00:00 10
2012-01-16T11:00:00 11

cat output.log
2012-01-16T10:00:04 10
2012-01-16T11:00:10 11
2012-01-16T12:00:00 12

sort -k2,2 input.log > input.sort
sort -k2,2 output.log > output.sort

join -a1 -j2 -o 0 1.1 2.1 input.sort output.sort | while read id i o; do
    if [ -n "$o" ]; then
        ot=$(date +%s -d "${o/T/ }")
        it=$(date +%s -d "${i/T/ }")
        [[ $it+5 -lt $ot ]] && echo $id $i $o
    else echo $id $i
    fi
done
11 2012-01-16T11:00:00 2012-01-16T11:00:10
9 2012-01-16T09:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

```
t1=2012-01-16T10:00:00
t2=2012-01-16T10:00:04
echo $(($(date -d $t1 +%s)-$(date -d $t2 +%s)))
-4
```

Comment: Looking at the output of `date -d "2012-01-16T10:00:00"`, the time component is 7 hours out, since T is the zone designator for UTC−07:00. It might happen consistently but would probably mask other date comparison issues, hence the replacement.

Comment: Hence what replacement? I don't understand your issue. `t2=2012-01-16M10:00:04` yields to `-68404`, or did I understand though?

Comment: I meant the replacement in my example; it would be `${t1/T/ }` in yours. In [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations), the T refers to the start of the time component, not a zone designator (which is omitted from the log timestamp as all our servers use UTC).

Comment: Well - if all servers use UTC, why bother?

Comment: Why bother with what? Regardless of the timezone of the servers, `date` **incorrectly parses** the above date string. Thankfully I'm computing the differences, which masks the error in this specific instance; however the actual Unix timestamp operands are each incorrect. `2012-01-16T10:00:00Z` is `1326708000`, not `1326682800`.

Comment: Well, but it is about the differences, not about the absolut value. Is there an error in building the difference?

Comment: There is no problem in the difference *in this particular example*. It might even work for my specific question. I was just pointing out that there is a known issue with this solution that could trip up other users of the code.